# JavaScript "unexpected identifier" in each loop - Why am I getting this error? Simple demo code within

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
function printClassForAllDivs()
{
    var divs = $('div');
    divs.each(function{
        var klass = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log('div class = '+klass);
    });
}
```

It seems to me that this code should loop over all the divs and for each iteration of the loop a variable should be created to store the class, which is then printed to the console.

I'm afraid I don't understand something about how to use the anonymous function.

```
function printClassForAllDivs()
{
    var divs = $('div');
    divs.each(function{
        // what don't I understand about what I am permitted to do in here?
    });
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
divs.each(function{
```

supposed to be

```
divs.each(function(){
```

Answer (score 4):

You are missing parentheses for the function inside `divs.each`.. See below,

```
divs.each(function (){
```

Change your code like below,

```
function printClassForAllDivs()
{
    var divs = $('div');
    divs.each(function (){
        var klass = $(this).attr('class');
        console.log('div class = '+klass);
    });
}
```